# Show loading image if Brightcove video is taking time to load on the page

Tags: jquery, loading, brightcove

I am using **Brightcove** video but its take a few seconds to appear/display on the screen. So in the meantime I want want to display the *loading.gif* image while the video is not loaded and once it loaded then hide *loading.gif*.

How to check if a Brightcove video is displaying on screen or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your code here on how you are loading and showing the video

i dont know how you are loading your video.. but heres a example on a ajax call processing some operations in server side.

```
  function ShowVideo(){}

  $("#div_Video" ).html("<img src='http://preloaders.net/preloaders/728/Skype%20balls%20loader.gif' />");

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "getVideo.....",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#div_Video").html(data); //replace the div with your video after loaded.. (i dont know how you are loading..)
            },
            fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("Error: " + textStatus);
            }
        });
```

}

first you load to the div where you will show the video the gif.. After the call to the server side be complete, replace the gif with the right code.

Answer (score 0):

I am using JS for load the Brightcove video .And i found below event,there we can hide the Loaded image .

```
 function onTemplateReady(event) {

                $(".load-image").hide();
                var $player = $(this);
            };
```